# maskMoney não funciona em input dentro tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, maskmoney

Aqui eu chamo a máscara usando classe

```
$(function($){
    $(".dinheiro").maskMoney();
});
```

nos inputs do formulário funciona normal, mas dentro tabela não funciona.

```
function addProd(obj) {
$('#add_prod').val('');
var id = $(obj).attr('data-id');
var name = $(obj).attr('data-name');
var price = $(obj).attr('data-price');

$('.searchresults').hide();

if ($('input[name="quant[' + id + ']"]').length == 0) {
    var tr =
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + id + ' - ' + name + '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<input type="number" name="quant" class="p_quant" value="1" onchange="updateSubtotal(this)" data-price="' + price + '" />' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' + price + '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<input type="text" name="servico[' + id.trim() + ']" class="servico" onkeyup="carregaServico(this)" id="servico[' + id.trim() + ']" data-type="search_servico" />' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td  width="10%" class="dinheiro">' +
        '<input type="text" name="vlr_servico[' + id.trim() + ']" data-id="' + id + '" onblur="formataDinheiro(this)" id="vlr_servico[' + id.trim() + ']" class="dinheiro" />' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="subtotal">' + price + '</td>' +
        '<td><a href="javascript:;" onclick="excluirProd(this)">Excluir</a></td>' +
        '</tr>';

    $('#products_table').append(tr);
}

updateTotal();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema consiste em atribuir a classe `.dinheiro` a um `td` e aos `inputs` que quer aplicar o `maskmoney`.

**Solução:** deixe apenas a classe `.dinheiro` aos `inputs` e faça um re-bind ao adicionar novos `inputs`.

```
<input type="text" class="dinheiro" />
```

Ao atribuir a classe á um elemento que não seja `input`, você causa erro no plugin, pois ele não irá reconhecer o valor a ser tratado.

```js
$(function($){
    $(".dinheiro").maskMoney();
});

function addProd(obj) {
   var tr =
   '<tr>' +
   '<td  width="10%">' +
   '<input type="text" class="dinheiro" />' +
   '</td>' +
   '</tr>';
   $('#products_table').append(tr);
   $(".dinheiro").maskMoney();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
<table id="products_table">
   <input type="text" class="dinheiro" />
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Add novo campo" onclick="addProd()" />
```

Comment: ja arrumei, era no template home estava chamando jquery 3.1 na view copiei link do datatables com jquery 1.12, ai deu erro

Comment: @JuniorRamoty Ah, que bom. Então posta uma resposta explicando como arrumou ou marca uma resposta pra não deixar a pergunta pendente. Boa noite!

Answer (score 0):

Ao executar `$(".dinheiro").maskMoney();` é feito um `bind` em todos os elementos com a classe `dinheiro` para usar a máscara.

Se você adicionar um novo elemento (como no caso da tabela), mesmo que ele tenha a classe `dinheiro`, o `bind` para os elementos já foi feito, logo, a máscara não deve funcionar para um novo elemento.

Para corrigir, basta fazer o `re-bind` da máscara para os elementos:

```
function addProd(obj) {
    // código da função...
    if ($('input[name="quant[' + id + ']"]').length == 0) {
        var tr = ...;

        $('#products_table').append(tr);
        //faz o re-bind caso tenha sido adicionado um novo input
        $(".dinheiro").maskMoney();
    }
    updateTotal();
}
```

Comment: ja tentei da erro TTypeError: $(...).maskMoney is not a function[Learn More] addprodOS.js:81:9
 addProd http://localhost/enginesystem/assets/js/addprodOS.js:81:9
 onclick http://localhost/enginesystem/os/add:1:1

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/enginesystem/assets/js/jquery.maskMoney.js"></script>  coloquei começo do template home , os outros inputs fora da tabela estao normais

Comment: ReferenceError: addProd is not defined[Learn More] add:1:1   da erro, to quebrano a cabeça desde ontem kkk

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69477/discussion-between-andre-gusmao-and-junior-ramoty).